# What's the right order when loading packages?

Tags: packages, preamble, incompatibility

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Non-commutative packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3090/non-commutative-packages)

I remember reading in some reference guide that the order of loading packages with `\usepackage` in principle doesn't matter. Real life, however, has taught me that in many cases latex packages do not have 'orthogonal' behaviour, so to speak: They might interfere with one another if loaded in the wrong order. A few examples:

- `biblatex` tells us to load it before `hyperref`
- `geometry` tells us to load it after `hyperref` in some special circumstances
- `hyperref` wants to be loaded as the very last package
- for the `ragged2e` package the LaTeX Companion advises: "The package should therefore be loaded *after* the body font and size have been established – for example, after font packages have been loaded."
- [Which packages should be loaded after hyperref instead of before?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before)
- [Should the fontenc package be loaded before or after font packages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2859/should-the-fontenc-package-be-loaded-before-or-after-font-packages)

And so on. Now: **Are there general best practices regarding package loading order in latex?** How can I know about dependencies? Are there even recommended ways of structuring the preamble (first layout, then fonts, then babel, then ...) to make sure there is no unwanted interference between packages and/or package configuration?

(I know it is a very general, but I hope still practical and useful question. Thanks!)

Comment: I don't think we need yet another one of these [questions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3090/non-commutative-packages). Voted to close.

Comment: I see. _That_ question subject was a bit difficult to find, though.