# loading lineno changes spacing in document

Tags: line-spacing, line-numbering

I loaded `lineno` to number the lines on my resume for critique by a professor. Doing so changed the spacing after the headers. I would like to number the lines and retain the original formatting, if possible.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\pagestyle{empty}
\raggedright

% Uncommenting lineno changes spacing below \header
%\usepackage{lineno}

\newcommand{\area}[2]{\vspace*{-9pt} \begin{verse}\textbf{#1}   #2 \end{verse}  }
\newcommand{\lineunder}{\vspace*{-8pt} \\ \hspace*{-18pt} \hrulefill \\}
\newcommand{\header}[1]{{\hspace*{-15pt}\vspace*{6pt} \textsc{#1}} \vspace*{-6pt} \lineunder}

\newcommand{\schoolwithcourses}[4]{
\textbf{#1} #2 $\bullet$ #3 $\bullet$ #4\\
Selected Coursework:\\
\vspace*{5pt}
}

\begin{document}

\header{Education}

\schoolwithcourses{Bachelor of Science}{$\bullet$ Georgia Gwinnett College}{May 2013 $\bullet$ Magna cum Laude}
{GPA: 3.874/4.000}
\area{Biology}{Microbiology $\cdot$ Immunology $\cdot$ Human Anatomy $\cdot$ Human Physiology $\cdot$ Biomechanics $\cdot$ Organic~Chemistry $\cdot$ Biotechnology $\cdot$ Biochemistry $\cdot$ Cell Biology }
\end{document}
```

Comment: The solution is to load `lineno` before `\raggedright`.

Comment: How would I ever know that?

Comment: To respond to your question about how you would know that, in this case I think the following rule of thumb could be followed: load all packages before using any commands that are related to actually typesetting text such as `\raggedright` (which usually would go after `\begin{document}`.)  This won't solve package loading order problems, but will prevent this sort of problem from arising.  See also [What's the right order when loading packages?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4515).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The general answer is:

**NEVER** use any command related to typesetting text (`\raggedright` in your case) in the preamble.

---

The specific answer in your case is:

`lineno.sty` redefines the meaning of `\\` (which you're using in your `\newcommand`s) and issuing `\raggedright` before that redefinition causes the conflict.

These are the lines in `lineno.sty` which cause the conflict:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\\{%
  \ifLineNumbers
    \expandafter \@LN@cr
  \else
    \expandafter \@normalcr
  \fi
}
```

`LineNumbers` is false in your case, so `\\` gets defined as `\@normalcr`, which is the "fragile" version of `\\`.