# Can't break a line in \maketitle with \raggedright

Tags: horizontal-alignment, titles

(This is, in a sense, a follow-up to [Insert text between title and author](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136285/insert-text-between-title-and-author)).

When using `\raggedright` in the preamble, LaTeX throws an error when I use a linebreak command `\\` in `\maketitle`. How can I circumvent this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\raggedright % turn off right-edge text justification and hyphenation
\usepackage{titling}
    \pretitle{\begin{flushleft}\LARGE\textbf} % left aligned title with LARGE bold type
    \posttitle{\vskip .25ex\hrule\par\end{flushleft}} % add hrule under title
    \preauthor{\begin{flushleft}\large} % left align author
    \postauthor{\par\end{flushleft}}
    \predate{\begin{flushleft}} % left align date
    \postdate{\par\end{flushleft}\vspace{-3ex}} % reduce space after \maketitle

\begin{document}
\title{Review}
\author{\textbf{Paul McCartney}\\ University of Liverpool}
\date{\today}
\maketitle
\noindent Here my review begins
\end{document}
```

> ! Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }.
>
> \par
>
> l.14 ...Paul McCartney}\ University of Liverpool}

Comment: You can substitute `\\ ` by `\hfil\break`. This will probably break other parts of the document (running heads, maybe).

Comment: I can't figure what is the exact cause in this case, but **never** use commands like `\raggedright` in the preamble (see this thread: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/132062/27635). Can't you anyway issue `\raggedright` after `\maketitle`?

Comment: @karlkoeller I'm puzzled by the principle "NEVER use any command related to typesetting text in the preamble." I would like to hear more about that.

Comment: @Sverre I can't remember now where I read something about it, but (probably I'm wrong) I can remember to have read that it is a good practice (at least one should issue such commands after having loaded all packages, although in your case it seems to be not enough).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually (not always, but here)

```
! Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }.
```

should be read as *Use of fragile command in a moving argument*.

So

```
\author{\textbf{Paul McCartney}\protect\\ University of Liverpool}
```

Works as intended without error.

Comment: I have no idea how to interpret "Use of fragile command in a moving argument", but ``\protect`` does indeed work.

Comment: @Sverre you interpret it as "you need `\protect` :-) see any of http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=fragile+protect+user%3A1090

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error while using the `titling` package in combination with the `tabular` environment:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[margin=0.9in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titling} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pretitle{\vspace{-35pt}\begin{flushleft}}

\title{
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
\Huge{Title} & \includegraphics[width = 0.2\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{tabular*}
}

\posttitle{\end{flushleft}\hrule\vspace{-50pt}}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

When I ignored this error and simply pressed enter a few times, I did get the pdf output, but it bothered me that I get this error every time I compile the document. I tried adding `\protect` at various locations in the code, but that did not help. I did find a solution in the `titling` package documentation, that uses `\DeclareRobustCommand`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[margin=0.9in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titling} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pretitle{\vspace{-35pt}\begin{flushleft}}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\desiredTitle}{
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
\Huge{Title} & \includegraphics[width = 0.2\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{tabular*}
}

\title{\desiredTitle}

\posttitle{\end{flushleft}\hrule\vspace{-50pt}}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

I was asking a question about the problem when I found this solution. I figured I'd place my findings here in case anyone else encounters this error in a similar situation.