# Any Overlapping or Misordering in My Preamble?

Tags: preamble

I've used both `hyperref` and `url` to enable `href` and `url`, but heard that they're redundant. Also I realized that ordering `\usepackage`s matters. For example,

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
```

applies doublespacing to footnotes, while

```
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

doesn't. So I'm trying to review all the preamble I've used to detect any unnecessary repetition or improper arrangement. Here's the code.

```
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}      % Give 1 inch margins
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}   % Use doublespacing and enable SPACING
\usepackage[pdfpagemode=UseNone,       % Suppress bookmarks in Acrobat
    pdfstartview=]{hyperref}           % Use a default zoom
\usepackage[round]{natbib}             % Alter brackets by parentheses
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,         % Make captions smaller
    labelsep=period,                   % Alter Table 1: by Table 1.
    skip=0pt]{caption}                 % Tune the gap between captions and tables
\usepackage[input-decimal-markers={.}, % Use decimal alignment
    group-separator={,},               % Give thousand separators
    parse-numbers=false]{siunitx}      % Use a math mode for S columns
\ExplSyntaxOn                          % Make SIUNITX be compatible with TABU
    \cs_new_eq:NN
    \siunitx_table_collect_begin:Nn
    \__siunitx_table_collect_begin:Nn
\ExplSyntaxOff
\usepackage{pdflscape,                 % Use a landscape mode with rotation
    xcolor,                            % Enable COLORBOX
    amsmath,                           % Use usual math syntax
    amssymb,                           % Use some math symbols
    amsthm,                            % Use theorem-like environments
    textcomp,                          % Enable TEXTMINUS
    cancel,                            % Enable CANCEL
    tabu,                              % Enable TABU and the X columns
    booktabs,                          % Enable TOPRULE, MIDRULE, BOTTOMRULE
    multirow,                          % Enable MULTIROW
    graphicx}                          % Enable INCLUDEGRAPHICS
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}              % Tune the padding setting of COLORBOXs
\theoremstyle{plain}                   % Apply PLAIN to these NEWTHEOREMs
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}    % Enable DEFINITION
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}  % Enable PROPOSITION
\newtheorem{hypothesis}{Hypothesis}    % Enable HYPOTHESIS
```

I'd appreciate any single comment in advance.

Comment: Some packages (usually which provide similar types of features) may require a specific order, other than that the order is usually irrelevant. One exception to the rule is `hyperref` which, aside very few exceptions, should be the very last package to be loaded. Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/134574, and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4515/134574

Comment: Real quick: it's *not true* that `hyperref` and `url` are redundant. Each package provides some functionality that the other does not. For sure, though, `url` must be loaded before `hyperref`. Indeed, as @PhelypeOleinik has already pointed out in a comment, with very few exceptions `hyperref` should always be *loaded last*. (One important exception to this rule is the `cleveref` package...)