# Change font in the Springer Verlag Class

Tags: fonts, templates

I am using the Springer Verlag Mongraph class [svmono.cls](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~rutte101/rrtex/styles/svmono.cls) for layouting my PhD dissertation. With a preamble, i am able on changing small things in this preamble, however i fail in changing the font type to e.g. [Kurier Light Condensed](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/kurierlc/). What is the easiest way to change the `\normalfont`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example (using `svmono.cls` as provided in your first link) works for me.

```
\documentclass{svmono}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[light,condensed,math]{kurier}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

(The [lipsum](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) package is only used to add some dummy text to the example.)

Comment: ha, it turned out that i wrote the fontenc and kurier line code too early in my preamble, if it are the last lines it indeed works perfectly !

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2859/should-the-fontenc-package-be-loaded-before-or-after-font-packages