# Incompatibility with french option in babel after last upgrade of Texlive

Tags: babel, debugging, french

After upgrading just now my TexLive with TexUtility, I got an incompatibility with french in babel

Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{amsart}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
c'est du français
\end{document}
```

It seems the problem comes from the installation of the e-french package instead of the frenchle one, but I do not know how to stop TexUtility doing its stuff. The only quick solution I found was to reinstall the MacTex 2015 installation and not upgrading it after. Any idea how to do better ?

Comment: I added a temporary fix in the other question, and reported the issue to texlive maintainers.

Comment: Try to respect order                                                    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dutch,french,british]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern} or look this post http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31940/my-french-%C3%A9-is-being-shown-as-a-weird-%C3%83l