# french language, correction, grammar

Tags: grammar

Grammar-checking tool for use with LaTeX?

I would like to know if there is a grammar correction software (french language)in Latex, i am using Texmaker for compilation. please help cause when i copied the text from Texmaker or pdf. i find a problème with the symbols :

> Le renforcement par des colonnes impliquent habituellement
>   l'incorporation d'une quantitÃ© non nÃ©gligeable de matiÃ¨re dans une
>   proportion qui varie de 10 Ã  70 pour cent du volume du sol initial.
>   La quantitÃ© de matÃ©riau ajoutÃ©e dÃ©pend de la technique adoptÃ©e
>   (colonnes ballastÃ©e, pieux de sable, colonne en sol traitÃ© au ciment
>   ou Ã  la chaux), ainsi que de la performance visÃ©e. Le renforcement
>   par colonnes peut Ãªtre adoptÃ© pour les sols gÃ©nÃ©ralement faibles,
>   tel que les argiles molles hautement compressibles - avec un module
>   d'Young $E < 3$ MPa et une de cohÃ©sion non drainÃ© $c_{u} < 30 \ kPa$
>   et sables meubles avec un frottement angle $\phi < 30^{\circ}$
>   (c.-Ã -d. nombre de coups $SPT < 10$).

the original texte from latex source is :

> Le renforcement par des colonnes impliquent habituellement
>   l'incorporation d'une quantité non négligeable de matière dans une
>   proportion qui varie de 10 à 70 pour cent du volume du sol initial. La
>   quantité de matériau ajoutée dépend de la technique adoptée (colonnes
>   ballastée, pieux de sable, colonne en sol traité au ciment ou à la
>   chaux), ainsi que de la performance visée. Le renforcement par
>   colonnes peut être adopté pour les sols généralement faibles, tel que
>   les argiles molles hautement compressibles - avec un module d'Young $E
>   < 3$ MPa et une de cohésion non drainé $c_{u} < 30 \ kPa$ et sables
>   meubles avec un frottement angle $\phi < 30^{\circ}$ (c.-à-d. nombre
>   de coups $SPT < 10$).

Comment: The reason for a result like this is almost always that the input encoding is misidentified.  The default encoding nowadays is UTF8, so if the pre-accented letters are in your file, that's how the file should be saved.  I can't say more, since you haven't identified the document class and whether you are setting `\inputenc` or `fontenc`.  As long as the encoding of the file is properly identified, you will very likely not need a grammar checker.

Comment: Could you provide a MWE? Are you using `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` or `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`? I would suggest to use TeXstudio and use its spelling tool.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31940 may help you.

Comment: this is the class of my file :
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside,openright]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   % LaTeX, comprend les accents ! utf8
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

Comment: The characters pasted above look like UTF-8 interpreted as `latin1` (or a cousin like `latin9`). So, either  `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` is in effect and we don't know it, or something is really messed up.

Comment: For the problem of copying accented letters from the pdf you might try `\usepackage{cmap}`, see https://ctan.org/pkg/cmap.

Answer (score 1):

For a grammar-checking tool, have a look at [antidote](https://www.antidote.info/fr/antidote-9/documentation/guide-utilisation/utilisation-avec-vos-logiciels/windows/latex). Sadly, it is not free. I do not know the price since our school paid for it.

This software is considered as the best when it comes to orthograph and grammar corrections. And I was surprise to learn, a few year ago, that it was compatible with LaTeX.

As for the trouble with cut and paste, it has to do with letter encoding (as suggested by @BarbaraBeeton and others). I had the same problem a few years ago while transfering tex document from my mac (with texshop) to my PC (with texwork). The problem was solve by working exclusively in utf8 on either computer.
Look at what encoding Texmaker use as a default.

Hope it help.

Comment: You should specify that there is a charge for this software.

Comment: @AndréC thank's, I didn't tought of mentioning it.