# What LaTeX fonts do I have to use when generating SVG diagrams such that they match the fonts used by MathJaX?

Tags: fonts, pstricks, conversion, svg

I want to create SVG diagrams for articles viewed on a site with MathJaX enabled. The diagrams are mainly created in PSTricks as follows.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=1cm,12pt,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](6,6)
\pstTriangle[PointNameA=\alpha,PointNameB=\beta,PointNameC=\gamma](4,1){A}(1,3){B}(5,5){C}
\pstCircleABC[linecolor=blue]{A}{B}{C}{O}
\rput[c](3,2.5){$\angle x y z = 30^\circ$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Once I compiled it with `dvisvgm <filename>` (file extension can be ignored) and feed it to an HTML page as follows,

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" async
            src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.2/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p><img src="test.svg" /></p>
    <p>
        Angle \(\angle x y z\) and \(\alpha, \beta, \gamma\).
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

I got disappointed result as follows.

[image]

Unfortunately, the font used by MathJax differs from ones used in my SVG diagrams.

## Question

What LaTeX fonts are available for all browsers and devices on the earth and match the fonts used by MathJaX?

Comment: Looks like mathjax supports multiple fonts http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/font-support.html so I guess you could use whichever one of those you've set it up to use.

Comment: I think you should ask the bonus question as a separate question with a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe most of this information is available from the [LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/allfonts.html).

- MathJax Tex. I'm not sure about
- [STIX](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/stix/)

  ```
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{stix}
  ```
- [Asana Math](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/asanamath/)

  ```
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont{Asana-Math}
  ```
- Neo Euler. There are a number of fonts that use Euler math, but I don't know what Neo refers to here. [New PX with Euler math](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/newpxeuler/) maybe?
- [Gyre Pagella](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/texgyrepagella/)

  ```
  \usepackage{tgpagella}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  ```
- [Gyre Termes](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/texgyretermes/)

  ```
  \usepackage{tgtermes}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  ```
- [Latin Modern](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/latinmodernroman/)

  ```
  \usepackage{lmodern}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  ```

Presumably, you could install the actual OTF fonts from their [repository](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/tree/master/fonts/HTML-CSS) and use them with `fontspec` and `xelatex`.

Comment: I wondered that myself. I don't know the answer and the only thing I ever recall seeing about it was this ancient page http://tex.loria.fr/ctan-doc/macros/latex/doc/html/fntguide/node26.html which suggests loading fontenc after the font to prevent loading T1-encoded fonts from the cmr family.

Comment: I suspect your best bet is going to be installing the exact fonts they use and selecting the appropriate one.

Comment: To use Termes or Pagella for math, you should be loading newtxtext and newtxmath or newpxtext and newpxmath. Just loading tgpagella or tgtermes will only change the text font.

Comment: @Corey, you're correct that `tgpagella` and `tgtermes` just set the text font. But `newpxtext` and `newtxtext` appear to use different text fonts (perhaps the X variants are just extensions?). The math fonts seem to be constructed from a bunch of other fonts like URWPalladioL-Ital and zplx-regular. I guess I'm not sure what MathJax is doing precisely.

Comment: The comment I responded to about package ordering seems to have disappeared. I completely forgot that I asked about this years ago. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2859/should-the-fontenc-package-be-loaded-before-or-after-font-packages

Answer (score 2):

Here, it's displayed correctly, after I have correctly set the path to the GS lib in the `dvisvgm` command line option.
See in particular this page: http://dvisvgm.bplaced.net/FAQ

For me, with Ghostscript installed by macports (on Mac), if I launch `dvisvgm  --libgs=/opt/local/bin/gs svg.dvi svg.svg` I obtain this:
[image]

Edit: with this MathJax setting:
[image]

Comment: The dvisvgm binary from MacPorts does not need the ``--libgs`` option, contrarily to the TeXLive/MacTeX one. There is some discussion on TL2018 pretest on whether the TeXLive or MacTeX one could also find the libgs.dylib in ``/opt/local/lib`` automatically. (you can also set ``LD_LIBRARY_PATH`` in the environment). By the way are you sure your ``--libgs`` is correct. It should a priori refer to the dylib, not to `gs` binary.

Comment: Without the `--libgs` option, the SVG obtained is missing some (Postscript?) parts of the graphic, on my installation. I have installed MacTeX 2017, but also other binaries tools not related to LaTeX via mac ports. `which gs` give me the path `/opt/local/bin/gs`. The lesson of my answer is that the problem is not related to fonts used in the `.tex` file, nor to the MathJax setting, but more likely to the `dvisvgm` usage.

Comment: don't you have a ``ligbs.9.dylib`` in `/opt/local/lib` ?

Comment: No, I don't have `ligbs.9.dylib` (probably a typo), but `libgs.9.dylib` on `/opt/local/lib`. But why this question? I don't have problem. By the way, I also found `gs` in `/usr/local/bin` (here `gs` is an alias to `gs-noX11` executable).

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from the official [site](http://dvisvgm.bplaced.net/Screenshots),

> In order to avoid these problems, call dvisvgm with option -n or
>   --no-fonts. It replaces the font elements by paths which are supported by nearly all SVG renderers.

[image]

With a note,

> However, as there are no longer font characters present in the SVG
>   file, the drawn text can’t be selected in the browser.

For me, it is not a big problem.